# GPO deploy local admins

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

Really need help with this.

I need to allow someone else to be administrator for client computers and servers but not for domain controller.

I was able to do that but whatever I do that user is allways part of administrators group and can logon to DC, create OU etc.

Steps

1. create domain user (TestAdmin)
2. create group (LocalAdmins)
3. add user to group (then make group primary and remove user from Domain Users group)
4. create GPO (gpoLocalAdmin)
5. edit policy (Windows Settings->Security Settings->Restricted Groups) new group -> select -> LocalAdmins
6. This group is member of (select -> administrators)
7. gpupdate

This policy is not deployed to domain controlers (different OU) but TestAdmin can logon and administer domain.

How to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I have two questions for you: Why did you remove the user from Domain Users? Have you run a GP Results against the Domain Controller's Computer Policy to see whether your policy is somehow applying?

Comment: What do you mean they can administer the domain? Are you saying that they can log onto the Domain Controllers?

Comment: Yes, logon to DC, edit other users, move objects etc. Full admin as on other servers. How can i check that policy is not somehow applying other than using gpresults

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use gpresult?

Comment: I misspoke in the above post. I was using gpresult to check if policy is applying and is not but to me it looks it is because that user can still logon to DC. I was looking for alternative method to check

Comment: It looks that if I add user to administrators group on any domain joined machine its automatically become domain administrator. I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Carlo OK, so who are the members of the Domain "Administrators" (also check Enterprise and Domain Admins)? maybe you'll find some horrific error someone made and added all local admins to the domain administrators...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, unless you have a really good reason, don't remove this user from `Domain Users`. Also, there is almost never a reason to change the primary group. IIRC this setting *exclusively* applies to POSIX applications, and has no bearing whatsoever on anything security related.

That aside, you have the right idea here. Add a domain user to a domain group, then use Group Policy to add the domain group to the local Administrators groups. You went wrong in step 5, where **you have the group membership reversed**.

In effect, what you just asked GP to do is "take a domain group and add it to the local administrators group. This sounds correct, but look a bit closer and realize which element you're asking Group Policy to modify - in this case, you're asking it to **modify the domain group by adding it to the local group, which will never work**. Since Group Policy is always processed on client systems, you can't ever modify domain accounts, *you can only modify local accounts*.

To get this working correctly, you need to ask group policy to **modify the local group by adding the domain group to it**. To do this,  open Restricted Groups, and start by selecting the Administrators group on the local system (don't worry, it will work for the corresponding group on *any system*):

[image: Add Restricted Group]

Then, modify it by adding the domain group as a member:

[image: Modify Restricted Group]

Comment: Thanks. I realized it, but I forgot to write here. Many thanks for great answer. I hope it will help someone in future.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you!